# Announcing a Pro Tempore Moderator Election for 2021

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators, election

**Summary**: Amateur Radio Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://ham.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **August 9** to bring in two more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on August 9, users can [nominate themselves](https://ham.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On August 16, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than three candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on August 24 (or August 31, if we need to extend the nomination period).

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

*If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.*

Comment: You have no idea how happy you've made me. :-)  I edited the title to make sure everyone understands  that this is about a *moderator* election.

Comment: I just discovered by looking at the edits to this question that ham.SE has a Twitter account, [@StackHam](https://twitter.com/StackHam).  I had no idea!  It tweets about ham.SE questions, presumably automatically.  There have been 1,922 tweets, and that user allegedly has 23 followers.

Answer (score 4):

I will probably [throw my hat in the ring](https://wordhistories.net/2018/06/30/throw-hat-ring/).

Answer (score 1):

**The election process has begun. You can nominate yourself until the deadline on August 15, which you can withdraw from until then.**

And so far, we only have [**ONE** person](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/a/449/8717) that has expressed an interested in being a moderator here!

**It will NOT consume a lot of your time.** ***We need help!*** :-)

If you might be interested, *What questions do you have?* Kindly post them here in an answer.